# Get CPU % used by Oracle session

Tags: performance, oracle, monitoring

I need to get the % of CPU that Oracle sessions are consuming.

I have tried the following script, this totals the CPU consumed by all sessions, and then calculates the  how much of CPU from that total each active session is consuming. But this does not really tell me how much of % of the CPU on the machine is consumed by an active session.

To give you an example, say a session is consuming 10% of total CPU consumed by all sessions. But that in reality is just 2% of the CPU power available on the server. I need to get that 2% figure.

```
WITH TOTAL_CPU AS
(
select 
   sum(VALUE/100) cpu_usage_seconds
from
   v$session ss, 
   v$sesstat se, 
   v$statname sn
where
   se.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
and
   NAME like '%CPU used by this session%'
and
   se.SID = ss.SID
--and 
   --ss.status='ACTIVE'
and 
  ss.username is not null)
select * from 
(
  select 
     ss.username || '-' || se.SID "Session",
     --VALUE/100 cpu_usage_seconds,
     sum(round(VALUE/(select * from TOTAL_CPU),2)) as CPU,
     (select * from TOTAL_CPU) as Total
  from
     v$session ss, 
     v$sesstat se, 
     v$statname sn
  where
     se.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  and
     NAME like '%CPU used by this session%'
  and
     se.SID = ss.SID
  and 
     ss.status='ACTIVE'
  and 
     ss.username is not null
  and value > 0
  group by ss.username, se.SID  
  order by CPU desc
)
where rownum < 11
order by CPU desc
```

Comment: IS this Windows or Unix/Linux?

Answer (score 1):

IF this is running on Windows you could use Process Explorer by Sysinternals.  Just go to the Oracle process the sessions are in & you should be able to see the CPU % by thread.  I'm not an Oracle DBA, but I'm assuming that each session is a thread on Windows.

If this is Unix/Linux, are sessions run a new thread also?  [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89659/how-do-i-monitor-cpu-core-usage-per-thread) is a link mentioning how to get that info on Unix/Linux.

Comment: It is Unix. I am afraid Windows threads and Oracle Sessions are quite different. Session is more like connection to Oracle that is doing something.

Comment: See this link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_killing_oracle_sessions.htm.  It suggests that on Windows, sessions are on a separate threads

Comment: That post also mentions on unix you need the PID, so on unix, sessions must be in a unique process